# I have to export the path everytime I return to mac terminal?

Tags: macos, shell, expo

I am using expo-cli and when i close my terminal and return back everytime I have to type command `export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.2/bin:$PATH"`.Path is where my expo-cli is installed. I have also added the path at the bottom of the file that opens on ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

The `expo-cli` requires `node` and it is not on your *default* `PATH`. Homebrew links binaries to `/usr/local/bin` from the Cellar by *default*.

> Check `brew --prefix` to be certain Homebrew is rooted @ `/usr/local`.

Your best options are:

1. Modify the `PATH` environment variable, like you are doing, in your `~/.bash_profile` or another bash startup file (e.g. `/etc/profile`).
2. Since you are on a Mac, you can modify your `PATH` globally by adding `/usr/local/bin` to `/etc/paths` or by adding `/usr/local/bin` to an arbitrary file inside `/etc/paths.d`.